# Test if a component is passing an @Input to another

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, typescript

I'm fairly new to unit testing. I wonder how I could test if a smart component is passing some as an `@Input()` to a dumb one (using Angular 4+).

At first, I thought about checking if the property exists:

```
it('should have some data', async(() => {
  expect(component.data).toBeTruthy();
}));
```

However, I faced two issues: 1) that tells me if `data` is true but doesn't necessarily means it's being passed as an input to my dumb component; 2) if the `data` property doesn't exist, then the test suite won't be executed.

Any tips? Is there a better way to approach this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since input bindings are processed as part of change detection you can basically change the property used in bindings on the parent component, then run `detectChanges()` on the parent component and check if the input property has changed in the child component. Something along these lines:

```
parentComponent = TestBed.createComponent(BannerComponent);
const childComponentEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(ChildComponent));
const childComponent = childComponentEl.injector.get(ChildComponent);

it('should have some data', async(() => {
  parentComponent.componentInstance.boundProperty = 3;
  parentComponent.detectChanges();
  expect(childComponent.inputProperty).toBe(3);
}));
```

You can read more about why input bindings update in:

- [Everything you need to know about change detection in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f)
- [The mechanics of property bindings update in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-mechanics-of-property-bindings-update-in-angular-39c0812bc4ce)